# Select() from LINQ in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, linq

Is it exist some alternative of LINQ Select() method in the Swift language?

As example, in c# I can do the following:

```
var ranks = cards.Select(a=> a.Rank).ToArray();
```

but how I can do the same thing using Swift language?

Comment: The `Rank` property of `Card` should be called `rank`, in line with Swift naming conventions. C# uses capitals for properties, and lowercase (or `_` prefix) for instance variables. Swift doesn't have instance variables, so there's no need for the distinction. Properties areLowerCamelCase, and capital camel case is reserved for types and static properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641748-map)

```
let ranks = cards.map{ $0.Rank }
```

which is syntactic sugar for:

```
let ranks = cards.map({ (card: Card) -> Rank in
    return card.rank
})
```

The applied syntactic sugar includes:

1. [Trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102)

   ```
   let ranks = cards.map { (card: Card) -> Rank in
       return card.rank
   }
   ```
2. Argument type inference

   ```
   let ranks = cards.map { card -> Rank in
       return card.rank
   }
   ```
3. Return type inference

   ```
   let ranks = cards.map { card in
       return card.rank
   }
   ```
4. Implicit return value

   ```
   let ranks = cards.map { card in
      card.rank
   }
   ```
5. Anonymous closure arguments

   ```
   let ranks = cards.map { $0.rank }
   ```

Check out the [language guide section on closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) (the Swift name for what C# calls *lambdas*) for more information,

Comment: Looks like this is it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andrew I gave break down of how the various syntactic sugars are applied to reach the final form I showed. It's covered in the language guide. You should definitely read it, it's very well written, and will be a breeze to understand if you already know C#.