# Parameters after opening bracket

Tags: swift, parameters, vapor

I am doing my first steps in Vapor, the web framework for Swift.

The first piece of code that called my attention was this:

```
app.get("welcome") { request in 
    return "Hello"
}
```

I don't understand the syntax here. I mean, I'm calling `app.get()` method, but I'm also defining some kind of function where request is a parameter. I know that this will result in a get method accessible by a `/welcome` URL and will return "Hello". What is not clear for me is how this piece of code works and how the compiler interprets it.

Comment: Do CMD+Click on `.get` and you will see the method declaration, it will be enlightening. :) Keywords: callback (completion handler) and trailing closures.

Comment: Oh. No Xcode, so... Vim? ;) Ok, you won't see the method declaration, but you can still have a look at those keywords. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343547/2227743), it shows a similar trailing closure example.

Comment: Thanks! I saw it is a completion handler. So it is just a callback. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).

I give a nice rundown of the various syntactic sugars of closures in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390414/3141234).

The expanded version of this code would be:

```
app.get("welcome", { (request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable in 
    return "Hello"
})
```