# Looking to understand Swift Functions a bit better

Tags: swift, function

I'm new to swift and have a lot of repeating code.  For example how would you change the following code into different functions:

## Example 1

```
if let button = view.viewWithTag(12) as? UIButton {
            // change any properties of the button as you would normally do
            button.isHidden = true
        }
```

## Example 2

```
var oneAPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var oneBPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var oneCPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var oneDPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var twoAPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var threeAPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var fourAPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
let oneASound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1-a", ofType: "mp3")
let oneBSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1-b", ofType: "mp3")
let oneCSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1-c", ofType: "mp3")
let oneDSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1-d", ofType: "mp3")
let twoASound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "2-a", ofType: "mp3")
let threeASound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3-a", ofType: "mp3")
let fourASound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "4-a", ofType: "mp3")
```

Comment: I can't give a good answer about what to do with the first section (all the `AVAudioPlayer` instances), but I wrote an answer to handle the second case. Let me know if you need me to explain any parts of it

Comment: This is a VERY good question. IMNSHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily use a new function for this. I would write it like so:

```
let soundNames = ["1-a", "1-b", "1-c", "1-d", "2-a", "3-a", "4-a"]
let sounds = soundNames.map{ Bundle.main.path(forResource: $0, ofType: "mp3") }
```

Comment: this is good, but maybe an array example would be a bit easier for a newcomer

Comment: @Fluidity I'll answer questions from OP as they come up, but I'm not a replacement for the language guide.

Comment: yes, the docsets do a great job of explaining FP and declarative paradigm.. especially to newcomers ;) Recursion and monads would be great starting material too.

Comment: @Fluidity I have no bearing on what OP's knowledge is like, and to start from first principles would be futile, my post would be no better (likely worse) than existing, popular, beginner resources. The whole upside to SO is that it's tailored information. In my answers I try to give the key information necessary in order for OP to know where to go next (what keywords to search for, for example), and elaborate as requested. But again, not a replacement for docs/tutorials.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Use `flatMap` instead of `map` so that it will prevent `nil` object and you can also use `url(forResource:withExtension:)` instead of using `path(forResource:ofType:)` and latter make `URL` instance from it.

Comment: I understand Alex, and it's a good philosophy to have. My only concern was that his / her first sentence was "I'm new to swift and have a lot of repeating code". since the declarative approach is literally one line here, it could have been tacked on to something without trailing closures and closure syntax xD but yes, it is the best way to do it. Still have my upvote

Comment: @NiravD I think force unwrapping would be more appropriate. I think it's better to crash to find bugs like misspelt file names, missing files, etc. than to silently ignore, and later wonder why they're missing.

Comment: I agree, force unwrapping is good for learning, probably bad for shipping code though :P

Comment: @Fluidity I'm of the opinion that newbies should *not* be handed forced unwrapped optionals, because they'd be prone for abuse. But tasteful, justified use is perfectly valid. Having a missing file or incorrect filename is an unrecoverable error, it's probably that it fails loudly than be ignored silently

Comment: @Fluidity IBOutlets are IUOs by the same logic. There's nothing you can do about an IBOutlet not being hooked up properly, and carrying on without one is probably never a reasonable idea, so it's better to force a crash

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov That was your thinking, I would follow optional wrapping to prevent app crashing.

Comment: @NiravD App crashing isn't always a bad thing. In this case, what's the alternative? How could you recover from an error like this?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I know app crashing isn't a bad thing, I'm saying is preventing app crashing is also a good habit. Anyway let it be every one has different thinking on this one.

Comment: @NiravD What would you do, in this situation?

Comment: Could you explain what this nesting of map and $0 do to achieve the "loop" over the collection?

Comment: @Confused `$0` is an "anonymous closure argument". That is to say, because the compiler knows that this closure takes 1 argument, rather than giving it a name, I just refer to it at the 0th argument. See this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/40390414/3141234

Comment: @Confused `map` iterates over an array of inputs, and maps them into an array of outputs, according to the closure given. In this case, the closure takes an input (one of the soundNames), and produces an output (the sound's path)

Comment: @Confused For example, `[1, 2, 3].map{ $0 * 2 }` produces `[2, 4, 6]`

Comment: so `sounds` is a new, filled array?

Comment: @Confused Yup. Play around with it!

Comment: Ok. That's fine, I grok that, i have a similar function I learnt from rickster or someone else around here to sort some textures for an app I'm working on. But, given this is an array, he misses out on what he wants, which is that the variables be named `oneASound`, `oneBSound`, `oneCSound`, `oneDSound`. These may well be notes of a scale, so he might really want those sounds named in this way. Is it possible to use this kind of functional trickery to create a dictionary with the right names for each element?

Comment: Or maybe push them into an array with these names, as variables?

Comment: Sorry, map and $0 and $1 are VERY new to me, and I'm much impressed with their power.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130766/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-confused).

Comment: Good way to teach @AlexanderMomchliov swift .map is really powerful than for statement. +1

Answer (score 3):

Alex answer is good, but it's pretty complicated for someone new. I would suggest learning the basics of functions before attempting functional programming (usage of .map, .filter, and other fun stuff).

Here is a simple example that you can modify in numerous ways to be more flexible if desired:

```
var sounds: [String:String] = [:]

func addSound(_ num: Int,_ letter: Character) {

  let key = String(num) + "-" + String(letter)
  sounds[key] = Bundle.main.path(forResource: key, ofType: "mp3")
}

// Usage:
addSound(1,"a")

print(sounds["1-a"])
```

What we are doing is using just one variable to hold the sounds in... You access your different sounds by typing in the string, as demonstrated in the usage section.

This is a dictionary, and they are very powerful. They work based on Key and Value.

So here we have key of "1-a" and the value will be the bundle that we added in the function.

The function basically just converts the input parameters, an integer and a Character, and turns it into a string that we can use with our Bundle and Dictionary.

---

---

If you want to add many sounds at one time, you can convert this to an array:

```
func addSounds(_ keys: [String]) {

  for key in keys {
    sounds[key] = Bundle.main.path(forResource: key, ofType: "mp3")
  }
}

// Usage:
addSounds( ["1-a", "1-b"])
print( sounds["1-b"])
```

This second example is exactly what Alex did, his version used `.map` which is actually a function that does basically the same thing as the `for` loop. It's a great feature, but it focuses on what's called *declarative programming* --which is great--but generally difficult to learn when just starting out.

Comment: I appreciate the effort in this post, +1

Comment: this is attractive code - it looks good, it reads good, and uncle bob would be proud.

Comment: @crashlog uncle bob would HATE my code :P I used a comment!!