# how to understand "add new instance methods by extentions" from apple's guidebook?

Tags: swift

In apple's document, when we are going to extend **type:Int**, we can write code like this:

[image]

Here is my questions:

Why can **print("Hello!")** work?

I mean that, in line 2: **func repetitions(task: () -> Void) {**, how computer can know parameter **task** is as same as **task()**.

why doesn't it work if I write code like this:

[image]

here is the code, thank you:

```
import Foundation

func printHello(){
    print("Hello!")
}

extension Int {
func repetitions(task: () -> Void) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            task()
        }
    }
}



3.repetitions (printHello){

}
```

Comment: This is an instance of trailing closure syntax, one of the many syntactic sugars invented to make closures more convenient to work with. I give a break down of them in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40390414/3141234).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass `printHello` then you do it like this:

```
3.repetitions(task: printHello)
```

This way uses [trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

```
3.repetitions {
    print("Hello!")
}
```

It is syntactic sugar for this:

```
3.repetitions(task: {
    print("Hello!")
})
```