# Swift 3: Difference between DispatchQueue.main.async{} and DispatcQueue.main.async(execute:{})?

Tags: ios, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

There's a very narrow semantic difference between the two, and I find myself wondering why both options exist. Are they in any way different functionally, or is one likely just an alias of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is called *trailing closure syntax*. It's a syntactic sugar for making closures easier to work with.

There are many other kinds of syntactic sugar features that pertain to closures, which I cover in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390414/3141234).

As always, I highly recommend the [Swift Language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94), which does a great job at explaining the basics like this.

Answer (score 13):

There is no difference at all. They are, in fact, the very same method.

To the compiler,

```
myQueue.async(execute: { foo() })
```

is exactly the same as

```
myQueue.async {
  foo()
}
```

When the last argument of any function or method is a function, you can pass that argument as a trailing closure instead of passing it inside the argument list. This is done in order to make higher-order functions such as `DispatchQueue.async` feel more like part of the language, reduce syntactic overhead and ease the creation of domain-specific languages.

There's documentation on trailing closure syntax [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).

And by the way, the idiomatic way to write my first example would be:

```
myQueue.async(execute: foo)
```

Comment: In this case, you may as well do: `myQueue.async(execute: foo)` :)

Comment: I tried to make the parallel more obvious, but yeah, that would be the more idiomatic way :)