# map high order function format in swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering why map format has to be `{( )}` rather than just `{ }`

```
func intersect(_ nums1: [Int], _ nums2: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    // the following is right
    var num1Reduce = nums1.reduce(0){ $0 + $ 1}

    /// the following is wrong ??
    var num2Dict = Dictionary(nums2.map{ $0, 1 }, uniquingKeysWith : +)

    // the following is right
    var num1Dict = Dictionary(nums1.map{ ($0, 1) }, uniquingKeysWith : +)

}
```

and I even see the following format `({ })`. I am totally confused!

```
let cars = peopleArray.map({ $0.cars })
print(cars)
```

Comment: The `( )` is creating a tuple. See the documentation for the `Dictionary` initializer that you are using.

Comment: @rmaddy, any useful url as a reference?

Comment: I explain every syntactic sugar for closures (apart from capture expressions) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390414/3141234). It takes it from verbose to Swifty, step by step. It's worth checking out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the following `Dictionary` [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init):

```
init<S>(_ keysAndValues: S, uniquingKeysWith combine: (Dictionary<Key, Value>.Value, Dictionary<Key, Value>.Value) throws -> Dictionary<Key, Value>.Value) rethrows where S : Sequence, S.Element == (Key, Value)
```

Note that `S` is a sequence where its elements are a tuple of key/value pairs.

When you pass `nums1.map{ ($0, 1) }` to the first parameter, you are creating an array of key/value tuples from `nums1`.

It fails when you use `nums2.map{ $0, 1 }` because that is missing the parentheses for the tuple.

Keep in mind that `nums1.map{ ($0, 1) }` is shorthand for `nums1.map({ ($0, 1) })`. That's all related to [trailing closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) which has nothing to do with the parentheses for the tuple that appear inside the `{ }`.

Answer (score 1):

A map is a function that takes a closure as a parameter. We can call the map and pass the parameter like we do for any other ordinary function call without removing the brackets `()`e.g

```
(0...100).map ({ _ in print("yeti")})
```

But swift allows us to remove the brackets as a way of shorthanding and we can write it like, hence eliminating the `()`

```
(0...100).map { _ in print("yeti")}
```

But incase you want to access individual values of the array elements, you can do so in two ways,

1. Given an array, you can access it's individual element using $0, which basically says, `Hey map, give me the first element at this current index`.

```
(0...100).map {$0}
```

2. Instead of using the default swift indexing, you decide to define the value you are accessing by giving it a readable variable name e.g

```
(0...100).map {element in}
```

This gets `$0` and assigns it to `element`, the `in` keyword basically tells the compiler that hey, `$0` is now `element` and we are going to use it after `in`. Otherwise if you remove the `in` keyword, the compiler says it doesn't know any variable called `element`.

For special collections like dictionaries, they have two values per index, i.e the `key` and `value`, therefore if you want to access the contents of a dictionary during the mapping, you can do it in two ways like above, a). use the default swift indexes, or give the values per index,  readable variable names. e.g

```
let dictionary = ["a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5]
dictionary.map{($0, $1)}
```

We use inner brackets `()` to let the compiler know that the collection we are mapping over has two values per index. Please note the inner parenthesis are creating a tuple

```
dictionary.map {(key, value) in }
```

Comment: You really should state (near the end of your answer) that the inner parentheses `( )` are creating a tuple.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Let me add that